# php echo entire html without using readfile

Tags: php, html, css, echo

As the tittle, is it possible to echo entire html and css?
I am using if's and each match needs to generate a different page.

Also, in the html code in the html code I need to echo variable that is enclosed inside a div and styled.

Any thoughts how I can achieve this?

I get the following error **syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting**

Thanks

```
    echo '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="mk">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

            <style type="text/css">
            @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&subset=cyrillic);
            @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&subset=cyrillic);
            @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One);

            *:focus { outline: none; }
            ::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0; }
            .animate { -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; }

            body { min-width: 300px; width: auto; max-width: 1100px; height: auto; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; background-color: white; }

            div#container {
                position: relative; float: left; clear: none;
                width: 100%; height: auto; margin: -3px 0 30px 0; padding: 0 0 50px 0;
                background-image: url(guide.jpg); background-position: center bottom; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;
                background-color: pink;
                -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px;
            }

            html body div#container form {
                position: relative; float: left; clear: none;
                width: 100%; height: auto; margin: 40px 0 0 0; padding: 0;
            }

            html body div#container form div#email-container {
                position: relative; float: left; clear: none; display: block;
                width: 100%; height: auto; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;                
                text-align: center;
            }
            html body div#container form div#email-container div#email-input {
                position: relative; float: none; clear: none; display: inline-block;

                width: auto; height: auto; margin: 0 auto; padding: 25px 40px;
                font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-size: 40px; letter-spacing: normal;

                -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px;
                background-color: rgba(26, 60, 88, 0.9); color: #ffffff;
                cursor: default;
            }


            label.styled {
                position: relative; float: left; clear: none; display: block;
                width: auto; height: auto; margin: 0; padding: 10px 20px; overflow: hidden;

                font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-size: 15px; letter-spacing: normal;

                -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px;
                background-color: #ffffff; color: rgba(128, 130, 132, 1); box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #b6b6b8; 
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            label.styled:before {
                position: absolute; float: none; clear: both; top: 0; left: 0; display: block;
                width: 40px; height: 40px; margin: 0 0 0 10px; padding: 0; 

                content: '✔';
                font-size: 60px;

                opacity: 0;
            }

            input.styled {
                display: none;
            }

input.styled:checked ~ label.styled {
  padding-left: 50px;
  opacity: 1;

  background-color: rgba(128, 130, 132, 0.9); color: #ffffff; box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px rgba(128, 130, 132, 0.9);;
}
input.styled:checked ~ label.styled:before {
  top: -10px; left: -2px;
  opacity: 1; color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}


        </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="container" class="animate">


    <form method="post" action="$action" class="animate">

        <input type="hidden" name="mode_login">
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="$redirect">
        <input type="hidden" name="accept_terms" value="yes">

            <div id="email-container">
            <div id="email-input">' . $_POST['fes-email'] . '</div>
            </div>

    </div>


    <input type="checkbox" class="styled animate" id="checkbox-tnc-accept">
    <label class="styled animate" for="checkbox-tnc-accept">Ги прифаќам Условите и правилата <br> за користење на овој сервис</label>

    <button type="submit" value="Enter">Продолжи</button>

    </form>




</body>
</html>';
```

Comment: The short answer is: yes. Can you show us some of your code?

Comment: `echo`? `include`? `file_get_contents`? It's unclear what you have against `readfile`, why you'd need `readfile` or something similar to begin with, and what problem you really have in the first place. Please provide some example.

Comment: You could also use the ifs and generate include files.

Comment: I am getting the following error **syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting**, I copy and paste the code inside echo'';. There are no errors in terms of escaping single and double quotations. So not sure why it won't work. @Halcyon

Comment: Don't use an additional `echo` and `;` inside `.` string concatenation.

Comment: @deceze Will the variable be displayed without?

Comment: `'...' . $_POST['fes-email'] . '...'` – Yes, that's what string concatenation is.

Comment: Here would be the reference to the manual if you want to look into it: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: @deceze I'm a newb... Umm, can echo handle full <style>? Still get the same error even after I fixed the concatenation.

Comment: @Boris The easiest way to help you is, if you post your entire code, say what results you get now (+ exact error messages), what output do you expect, what you have tried and where are you stuck, so we can show you the errors and explain how to fix it and what's going on, so that next time you can fix your code yourself :D

Comment: @Rizier123 Full code is posted. Echo is inside IF. Php code worked fine before html was pasted. Expected outcome, this is a page that will display two different pages based of IF. Is  this possible?

Comment: Please read this: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/) – And then look closely at your use of `'` single quotes again. And then learn about HEREDOC. And then learn about separating your templates from PHP code entirely.

Comment: @deceze Theres a problem with the quotes is that why it isn't working or?

Comment: Yes, look very closely at "Fjalla One" in your code.

Comment: That was copied from google. Totally missed it. Thank you. It works now. I know it's better to not do it this way, but needs to this time at least @deceze

Comment: No, it doesn't. But suit yourself... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to not print html stuff with php, just close the php tags and write normal html, so here i removed the big echo statement and wrote normal html. This makes the code more clean and you see better what is html and where is PHP.

So your php code:

```
<div id="email-input">' . $_POST['fes-email'] . '</div>
```

If you don't have it in a echo statement just use this:

```
<div id="email-input"><?= $_POST['fes-email'] ?></div>
```

This is pretty much the same as:

```
<div id="email-input"><?php echo $_POST['fes-email']; ?></div>
```

Also for useful error messages you can turn on error reporting with this lines:

```
<?php
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

You can just put them on top of your php files and make sure that they are only turned on in staging!

The entire code should look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="mk">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

            <style type="text/css">

                @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&subset=cyrillic);
                @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&subset=cyrillic);
                @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One);

                *:focus { outline: none; }
                ::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0; }
                .animate { -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; }

                body { min-width: 300px; width: auto; max-width: 1100px; height: auto; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; background-color: white; }

                div#container {
                    position: relative; float: left; clear: none;
                    width: 100%; height: auto; margin: -3px 0 30px 0; padding: 0 0 50px 0;
                    background-image: url(guide.jpg); background-position: center bottom; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;
                    background-color: pink;
                    -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px;
                }

                html body div#container form {
                    position: relative; float: left; clear: none;
                    width: 100%; height: auto; margin: 40px 0 0 0; padding: 0;
                }

                html body div#container form div#email-container {
                    position: relative; float: left; clear: none; display: block;
                    width: 100%; height: auto; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;                
                    text-align: center;
                }
                html body div#container form div#email-container div#email-input {
                    position: relative; float: none; clear: none; display: inline-block;

                    width: auto; height: auto; margin: 0 auto; padding: 25px 40px;
                    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-size: 40px; letter-spacing: normal;

                    -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px;
                    background-color: rgba(26, 60, 88, 0.9); color: #ffffff;
                    cursor: default;
                }


                label.styled {
                    position: relative; float: left; clear: none; display: block;
                    width: auto; height: auto; margin: 0; padding: 10px 20px; overflow: hidden;

                    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-size: 15px; letter-spacing: normal;

                    -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px;
                    background-color: #ffffff; color: rgba(128, 130, 132, 1); box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #b6b6b8; 
                    cursor: pointer;
                }

                label.styled:before {
                    position: absolute; float: none; clear: both; top: 0; left: 0; display: block;
                    width: 40px; height: 40px; margin: 0 0 0 10px; padding: 0; 

                    content: '✔';
                    font-size: 60px;

                    opacity: 0;
                }

                input.styled {
                    display: none;
                }

                input.styled:checked ~ label.styled {
                  padding-left: 50px;
                  opacity: 1;

                  background-color: rgba(128, 130, 132, 0.9); color: #ffffff; box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px rgba(128, 130, 132, 0.9);;
                }
                input.styled:checked ~ label.styled:before {
                  top: -10px; left: -2px;
                  opacity: 1; color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
                }


        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="container" class="animate">

        <form method="post" action="$action" class="animate">

            <input type="hidden" name="mode_login">
            <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="$redirect">
            <input type="hidden" name="accept_terms" value="yes">

            <div id="email-container">
                <div id="email-input"><?= $_POST['fes-email'] ?></div>
            </div>

        </div>


            <input type="checkbox" class="styled animate" id="checkbox-tnc-accept">
            <label class="styled animate" for="checkbox-tnc-accept">Ги прифаќам Условите и правилата <br> за користење на овој сервис</label>

            <button type="submit" value="Enter">Продолжи</button>

    </form>




    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**

If you have this echo statement in a if statement you still don't need to print it that way :D

As a example (Pseudo Code):

```
<?php

    if(condition) {
        echo "<div>HTML STUFF</div>";  //Don't do it that way
    } else {
?>

<div>Put your HTML stuff here</div>

<?php
    }
?>
```

Also if you have to concatenate stuff:

```
                   //v Your variable here
  "String is here" . $myVariable . " string goes further"
//^String start  ^ ^Concatenate  ^ ^                    ^String ends
              // |Break the string |
```

And for more information about concatenation see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

I would also recommend you to not write CSS inline or in style tags. You can write your own CSS files with `*.css` and then include them in the html head tag with this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourCssFile.css">
```

Comment: I know it's better that way. But for this specific purpose, I need the code to be generated based on the IF's.

Comment: Can I achieve this in some way, shape or form?

Comment: @Boris Updated my answer, hope it helps you and you understand everything! Otherwise just ask if something is unclear

Comment: All clear thanks...Problem was I had copied font-family in my css from google fonts and it was single quote instead of double....

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '...assuming the previous part of the entire code are also present...
<form>    
<div id="email-input">' . $_POST['fes-email']; . '</div>
</form>
...';
```

Take notice that before $_POST I've removed the echo; If you're already echoing there's no reason to start the echo. When you post ' . $_POST['fes-email'] . ' You're just allowing a variable; it's been running the echo the whole time, so all the new echo does is confuse it. If you have to have it this way then it might be better to have something along the lines of

- htdocs(folder)
- index.php(file)
- includes(folder)
- includes/YourForm.php
  Then within YourForm.php add the HTML that you want to have then within index.php add

  require_once("includes/YourForm.php");

While I don't agree with the way you're doing it right now what I posted should work.
Not sure why the require isn't formatting as code.. Sorry.

Comment: I know. I've removed the echo. But still get the same error. Don't know why... I posted the full code if you want to take a look.

Comment: For that I'd definitely say use an include. I'll look deeper when I get to my computer. Also! Post the exact error. It will say exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you echo HTML in a `PHP` file . what you can do is , you can include HTML files in your condition . example :-

```
if(condition 1) 
{
   include "one.php";
}
else if(condition 2)
{
  include "two.php";
}
```

in your one.php and two.php you have your HTML , in your case your all HTML will go to one of these files . in that file you can echo your variable

```
<div id="email-input"><?php echo $_POST['fes-email']; ?></div>
```

Comment: Well, glad someone convinced him.